# Var dumper is printing to screen instead of toolbar

Tags: php, symfony, entity, dump, symfony4

I'm calling `dump()` from within an entity, but it is printing to the screen instead of the toolbar.

To compound the problem, this is on a form submission that redirects on successful completion, so the dump flashes to the screen before redirecting.

I'm using Symfony 4 if that makes any difference.

How do I get a `dump()` command to appear in the bottom web toolbar, instead of printing to the screen, when calling from an entity?

Answer (score 0):

is because you're being redirected.
in your config_dev.yml toggle intercept redirect to "true".

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: true
```

in this way, all redirections will be intercepted in dev mode. it will make it easier for you to debug.

Comment: Thanks, this solves part of the problem. However, I used to get an icon in the toolbar that showed vars dumped when clicked. Does that no longer exist?

Comment: In theory, the target dump icon appears in the toolbar when it is inserted into the PHP code. If it is inserted in a twig view, it appears directly in the view.